# PHPMailer's AddEmbeddedImage gives me blank emails

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am having a problem getting inline images to work using PHPMailer.  Without the following line (i.e. if I comment it out)

```
$success = $mail->AddEmbeddedImage($ImagePath, $ImageCID, $ImageName, $ImageEncoding, $ImageType, $ImageDisposition);
```

it works fine.  If I add it back in, I get a blank email (tried Outlook as well as Gmail).  I added the "$success = " to make sure it was working and it is.

```
<?php
$BaseURL = "../other/";
require_once($BaseURL . 'PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
require_once($BaseURL . 'PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php');
require_once($BaseURL . 'PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php');
require_once($BaseURL . 'PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php');

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// Test data begin
$encoding =""; // Also tried "base64"
$type=""; // Also tried "application/octet-stream" and "image/jpeg"
$disposition = "inline";
$ImageArray = array("../images/Logo.jpg|Logo|Logo.jpg|" . $encoding . "|" . $type . "|" . $disposition,
                    "../images/XX1.jpg|XX1|XX1.jpg|" . $encoding . "|" . $type . "|" . $disposition);
$Body = '<html><body style="font-family:Verdana, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#666666;">';
$Body .= 'This is a test from SendEmail and contains default text in the message body.';
$Body .= 'And an image... <img src="cid:Logo">';
$Body .= '<br><br></body></html>';
$SendParams = array("SendTo"=>array("xx@gmail.com, XX", "xx@example.com, XX/example"), 
                    "Body"=>$Body,
                    "Subject"=>"This is the default Subject",
                    "Images"=>$ImageArray
                    );
SendEmail($SendParams);
// End Test data and calls

function SendEmail($params) {
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
    $mail->Port = 587; //use port 465 when using SMPTSecure = 'ssl'
    $mail->Username = "exampele@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";    // $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
    if (!isset($params)) {
        die("Kaput!");
    }
    $SendTo = isset($params["SendTo"]) ?  $params["SendTo"] : array("xx@example.com, XX/example");
    $Body = isset($params["Body"]) ?  $params["Body"] : "No Message Body - may be a Test!";
    $Subject = isset($params["Subject"]) ?  $params["Subject"] : "No Message Subject - may be a Test!";
    foreach($SendTo as $recipient) {
        $recipient_array = explode(",", $recipient);
        $SendEmail = $recipient_array[0];
        $SendName = $recipient_array[1];
        $mail->AddAddress($SendEmail, $SendName);
    }
    if (isset($params["Images"])) {
        foreach($params["Images"] as $ImageData) {
            $ImageData_array = explode("|", $ImageData);
            $ImagePath = $ImageData_array[0];
            $ImageCID = $ImageData_array[1];
            $ImageName = $ImageData_array[2];
            $ImageEncoding = $ImageData_array[3];
            $ImageType = $ImageData_array[4];
            $ImageDisposition = $ImageData_array[5];
            // Below is the line causing the problem
            $success = $mail->AddEmbeddedImage($ImagePath, $ImageCID, $ImageName, $ImageEncoding, $ImageType, $ImageDisposition);
            // The below prints expected values for the variables ("Failed!" does not print)
            if ($success)
                echo "<br><br>Image: " . $ImagePath . ", " . $ImageCID . ", " . $ImageName . ", " . $ImageEncoding . ", " . $ImageType . ", " . $ImageDisposition;
            else
                echo "Failed!";
        }
    }
    $mail->Body = $Body;
    $mail->Subject = $Subject;
    $mail->SetFrom('admin@example.com', 'example Admin');
    $mail->addReplyTo('admin@example.com');
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
     } else {
        echo "Message sent!";
    }
}
?>
```

This is the screen output:

> Image: ../images/Logo.jpg, Logo, Logo.jpg, , , inline
>
> Image: ../podbanks/images/XX.jpg, XX, XX.jpg, , , inline
>
> ---
>
> mail: object(PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer)#1 (71) { ["Priority"]=>
> NULL ["CharSet"]=> string(10) "iso-8859-1" ["ContentType"]=> string(9)
> "text/html" ["Encoding"]=> string(4) "8bit" ["ErrorInfo"]=> string(0)
> "" ["From"]=> string(18) "admin@example.com" ["FromName"]=> string(14)
> "example Admin" ["Sender"]=> string(18) "admin@example.com"
> ["Subject"]=> string(27) "This is the default Subject" ["Body"]=>
> string(215) "This is a test from SendEmail and contains default text
> in the message body.And an image..." ["AltBody"]=> string(0) ""
> ["Ical"]=> string(0) "" ["MIMEBody":protected]=> string(0) ""
> ["MIMEHeader":protected]=> string(0) "" ["mailHeader":protected]=>
> string(0) "" ["WordWrap"]=> int(0) ["Mailer"]=> string(4) "smtp"
> ["Sendmail"]=> string(18) "/usr/sbin/sendmail"
> ["UseSendmailOptions"]=> bool(true) ["ConfirmReadingTo"]=> string(0)
> "" ["Hostname"]=> string(0) "" ["MessageID"]=> string(0) ""
> ["MessageDate"]=> string(0) "" ["Host"]=> string(14) "smtp.gmail.com"
> ["Port"]=> int(587) ["Helo"]=> string(0) "" ["SMTPSecure"]=> string(3)
> "tls" ["SMTPAutoTLS"]=> bool(true) ["SMTPAuth"]=> bool(true)
> ["SMTPOptions"]=> array(0) { } ["Username"]=> string(22)
> "examplemail@gmail.com" ["Password"]=> string(16) "shotlzacfvdubehm"
> ["AuthType"]=> string(0) "" ["oauth":protected]=> NULL ["Timeout"]=>
> int(300) ["SMTPDebug"]=> int(0) ["Debugoutput"]=> string(4) "html"
> ["SMTPKeepAlive"]=> bool(false) ["SingleTo"]=> bool(false)
> ["SingleToArray":protected]=> array(0) { } ["do_verp"]=> bool(false)
> ["AllowEmpty"]=> bool(false) ["DKIM_selector"]=> string(0) ""
> ["DKIM_identity"]=> string(0) "" ["DKIM_passphrase"]=> string(0) ""
> ["DKIM_domain"]=> string(0) "" ["DKIM_private"]=> string(0) ""
> ["DKIM_private_string"]=> string(0) "" ["action_function"]=> string(0)
> "" ["XMailer"]=> string(0) "" ["smtp":protected]=> NULL
> ["to":protected]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(19)
> "aa@gmail.com" [1](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/files/src-phpmailer.html)=> string(10) "AA" } [1](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/files/src-phpmailer.html)=> array(2) { [0]=>
> string(15) "aa@example.com" [1](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/files/src-phpmailer.html)=> string(13) "A/example" } }
> ["cc":protected]=> array(0) { } ["bcc":protected]=> array(0) { }
> ["ReplyTo":protected]=> array(1) { ["admin@example.com"]=> array(2) {
> [0]=> string(18) "admin@example.com" [1](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/files/src-phpmailer.html)=> string(0) "" } }
> ["all_recipients":protected]=> array(2) { ["aa@gmail.com"]=>
> bool(true) ["ag@example.com"]=> bool(true) }
> ["RecipientsQueue":protected]=> array(0) { }
> ["ReplyToQueue":protected]=> array(0) { } ["attachment":protected]=>
> array(2) { [0]=> array(8) { [0]=> string(31)
> "../images/clients/Logo.jpg" [1](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/files/src-phpmailer.html)=> string(13) "Logo.jpg" [2](https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/PHPMailer/addEmbeddedImage/php-phpmailer-addembeddedimage-method-examples.html)=>
> string(13) "Logo.jpg" [3]=> string(0) "" [4]=> string(10) "image/jpeg"
> [5]=> bool(false) [6]=> string(6) "inline" [7]=> string(9) "Logo" }
> [1](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/files/src-phpmailer.html)=> array(8) { [0]=> string(35) "../images/XX.jpg" [1](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/files/src-phpmailer.html)=> string(16)
> "XX.jpg" [2](https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/PHPMailer/addEmbeddedImage/php-phpmailer-addembeddedimage-method-examples.html)=> string(16) "XX.jpg" [3]=> string(0) "" [4]=> string(10)
> "image/jpeg" [5]=> bool(false) [6]=> string(6) "inline" [7]=>
> string(3) "XX" } } ["CustomHeader":protected]=> array(0) { }
> ["lastMessageID":protected]=> string(0) ""
> ["message_type":protected]=> string(0) "" ["boundary":protected]=>
> array(0) { } ["language":protected]=> array(0) { }
> ["error_count":protected]=> int(0) ["sign_cert_file":protected]=>
> string(0) "" ["sign_key_file":protected]=> string(0) ""
> ["sign_extracerts_file":protected]=> string(0) ""
> ["sign_key_pass":protected]=> string(0) "" ["exceptions":protected]=>
> bool(false) ["uniqueid":protected]=> string(0) "" } Message sent!

I also can't find any comprehensive documentation - not even on [GitHub](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/files/src-phpmailer.html) :3731.  The closest I have come is [this](https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/PHPMailer/addEmbeddedImage/php-phpmailer-addembeddedimage-method-examples.html).  But I still don't understand exactly what that third parameter is doing.  Do I want to override the name?  Why?  And what encoding should I use (I tried Base64 and blank both)?  What options exist other than "inline" for disposition? And so on...

Answer (score 1):

Before anything else, it looks like you're using an old version of PHPMailer, as you have a reference to a file that has not been part of the library for several years (the autoloader), so update.

Your code looks like it is based on a very old example. You should not set `Mailer` yourself – `isSMTP()` does that for you.

You might want to override the name if the file on disk has a different name that you don't want to expose to the recipient, for example you might have `logo-123456.png` locally, and want to attach it as `logo.png`.

The encoding will nearly always need to be `base64` because images tend to be binary and thus email-unsafe, so leave that as the default.

The MIME type should match the file extension, so you should be able to ignore that too (PHPMailer will set it for you), unless you have a very specific reason to set a MIME type that does *not* match your content.

`$disposition` sets the `Content-Disposition` header from [RFC2183](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2183). It doesn't make much sense to use anything other than `inline` for an embedded image, so you should leave that as its default too. The option is there because the RFC says it should be.

The upshot of all that is that all you actually need to provide is the path to the file and the `cid`.

It might help if you showed your SMTP transcript (set `SMTPDebug = 2`) as that will expose exactly what's happening in your message.

Comment: Thanx.  I am using version 5.5 which is older but not too old.  I am using legacy code, which we want to upgrade but it's a process.  Meanwhile, when you say leave certain variables to the default, can I set it to a blank string ie. "".  I want to do that to make it future compatible.  Also, without disposition inline, it will attach the images and will not make them inline, I believe.

Comment: Also, I do not understand "You should not set Mailer yourself – isSMTP() does that for you."  Can you please explain what I should do?

Comment: Yes, 5.2 (the last major version before 6.x; there is no 5.5) *is* very old and has not been supported since 2017. If you want to know how to upgrade to 6.x, read the upgrade docs that come with PHPMailer. Optional params in any PHP function call can simply be omitted; Setting them to an empty string will likely cause problems if that's not what you explicitly wanted to do. Delete the line that says `$mail->Mailer = "smtp";`; it's doing nothing.

Comment: Sorry, yes that was PHP 5.5 that I saw.  The VERSION file in my PHPMailer directory says 6.0.5  I had problems with installing Composer on the server and since it is a production server, I cannot experiment, so I installed manually.

Comment: It works when I remove the last three options (ImageEncoding, ImageType, ImageDisposition) but that is disappointing because my code is not future friendly i.e. for other formats and for images as attachments.

Comment: If the values you’re providing don’t work, they must be invalid or inappropriate. It will work fine in future. These standards are already decades old and they’re not about to change. If you want attachments, use `addAttachment`, not `addEmbeddedImage`.

Comment: I appreciate you inputs @Synchro, but if you recall, I am using blank values as well as the default but explicitly e.g. $encoding =""; // Also tried "base64"

Comment: Well don’t do that as it won’t work.